# 2D string array is storing '\0' when it encounters a word with more than one space or digit

Tags: c, arrays

I am pretty new to C programming. My program is supposed to take a string and move it into a 2D array. With the words either being separated by a white-space or a digit. This works perfectly fine if there is one space or digit separating it. However, as soon as there is more than one it starts adding '\0' to my array.

```
//Move the string into a 2D array
for(i = 0; i < total + 1; i++)
{
    if(isalpha( *(tempString + i) ))
    {
        sortingArray[n][j++] = tempString[i];
        input++;
    }
    else
    {
        sortingArray[n][j++] = '\0';
        n++;
        j = 0;
    }
    if(tempString[i] == '\0')
        break;

}
```

This is a sample of what happens (n = number of rows placed)

./a.out "one  more  way"

5  inputs

before

one

more

way

After

one

more

way

Comment: Why are you incrementing `j` and then setting it to zero without using the post-incrementation value?

Comment: What is `total`? This is not a [mcve].

Comment: Total in this test case is equal to 14 **I just noticed i don't need total +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip consecutive delimiters:

```
for(i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    if(isalpha(tempString[i]))
    {
        sortingArray[n][j] = tempString[i];
        ++j;
        ++input;
    }
    else
    {
        // skip consecutive delimiters
        while (i < total && !isalpha(tempString[i]))
            ++i;

        sortingArray[n][j] = '\0';
        ++j
        ++n;
        j = 0;
    }    
}
```

Disclaimer: not verified by a compiler. Use caution!

I also took the liberty of some improvements to your original code.

- there is no sense to check for `\0` if you have the length of the string.
- changed `*(tempString + i)` to the clear `tempString[i]`
- moved the increments out of the larger expressions into their own full expression. It is clearer this way.

Comment: It almost works! It just truncates the words so for the input "One  more  way" it prints it as one ore

Comment: @onbu you got the ideea. You need to take it further yourself and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple logic failure for which a debugger is ideal for identifying.

Imagine you have the string "hello  world".

It stores "hello" into `sortingArray[0]` easily enough. When it gets to the first space it increments `n` and starts looking for the next word. But the next character it finds is another space so it increments `n` again.

A slight change is required to your logic

```
if(isalpha( *(tempString + i) ))
{
    sortingArray[n][j++] = tempString[i];
    input++;
}
else if(j>0)
{
    sortingArray[n][j++] = '\0';
    n++;
    j = 0;
}
```

Now the code will only increment `n` if the previous character was a letter (by virtue of `j` being more than 0). Otherwise if it doesn't care and will keep going.

You should also check to see if `j` is non-zero after the loop as that means there is a new entry in sortingArray that needs a `NUL` added.

One thing also to note is that the way you're doing the `for` loop is a little odd. You have this

```
for(i = 0; i < total + 1; i++)
```

but also this inside the loop

```
if(tempString[i] == '\0')
    break;
```

Typically, the way to terminate the `for` loop would be to write it like this

```
for(i = 0; tempString[i]!='\0'; i++)
```

as that way you firstly don't care about the length of the string, but the loop will finish when it hits the NUL character.